# null pointer exception can't be fixed

Tags: java, mysql

I'm implementing a software for a stock management system in java.I'm using MVC design pattern and i found this exception when trying to fill a JcomboBox. I want to get all the batches when a item-code is being passed into the method.so the method should return a array-list of relevant objects. but when I run this program it gave me this kinda error and it says there is empty result set. but i also tried the sql code manually in the terminal and it worked. so i can't imagine how to fix this error. i'm glad if anyone can tell me where is the problem. I tried to post my screen shots but it cannot be done as i don't have enough reputation

here is my code

```
  String sql = "select batchNo from MainBatch where itemCode = ?";
    Connection c=DBConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps=c.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, itemCode);
    System.out.println(itemCode+" -----> item code is thiss");
    ResultSet set=ps.executeQuery();
    ArrayList<MainBatch> list=new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println(set.next()+" <-----result set is");
    while (set.next()) {
        MainBatch batch=new MainBatch(set.getString("batchNo"));
        list.add(batch);
    }
    return list;
```

[

Comment: can you provide console/server log ?

Comment: try removing the line "System.out.println(set.next()+" <-----result set is");" i think this is where your problem is

Comment: you are manualy moving the cursor of the ResultSet before the while loop, and in the while no result is found

Comment: Check your connection string. Ensure that your connection was established with mysql server. Post your log here.

Comment: @Kumar u mean a screenshot of the command prompt??

Comment: *"null pointer exception can't be fixed"* - So if it cannot be fixed, why are you asking us about it???  Hint: if it cannot be fixed, then nobody can fix it.  What you actually mean is that you cannot fix it.  And probably that isn't true either.

Comment: You have accepted the answer but still commenting. Your problem got solved? Debug the program line by line with break lines and check it.

Comment: @StephenC i asked for help cuz i thought it was smthing wrong with my code that's why I asked you

Comment: can you post stacktrace, and the line where the error occurs?

Comment: @Kumar it still not working. it is true I accepted an answer. it was my bad. all the other interfaces work properly but this. all of them uses the same class to connect with the database. but this is not working. but the sql query works manually. and it says set.next() returns false when I tried to run my program

Comment: @Nadusha - You entirely missed the point of my comment.

Comment: Create a new class and write a new code. Check the connection string properly. I think you may misspelled the database name. Check once. If you set everything correctly then it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

`ResultSet.next()` moves the result set's cursor to the next row. When you print it, before the `while` loop, you're losing the first row (or the only row in a single row result set). Personally, I'd just omit it, but if you have to have it, you could extract the result to a local variable:

```
boolean next = set.next();
System.out.println(next + " <-----result set is");
while (next) {
    MainBatch batch=new MainBatch(set.getString("batchNo"));
    list.add(batch);
    next = set.next();
}
return list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line.

```
System.out.println(set.next()+" <-----result set is");
```

You are calling set.next() twise, this moves the resultset pointer to next row.

Comment: Still getting same exception? Then share the exception stacktrace to see the exception caused line!

Comment: @Nadusha Check connection is established or not

Connection connection=DBConnection.getInstance().getConnection();